# Rails 2.3.4 Geokit error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, geokit

I have a rails application. `Rails version is 2.3.4` and `ruby version 1.8.7`. In that application I used `geokit (1.5.0) gem` and `geokit-rail`s plugin to find nearest location.

And in my **model** I have code like this,

```
class Notary < ActiveRecord::Base

acts_as_mappable

end
```

And in my **controller** have code like this,

```
class Client::OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def find_notary
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @miles = 10
    unless params[:notary_search]
      @notaries = Notary.find(:all, :origin => @order.signing_location_zip_code, :within => @miles, :conditions => "on_vacation IS NOT true",:order=>"distance asc" )
    else
    some code
    end
end

end
```

I am getting **error** in that line

> @notaries = Notary.find(:all, :origin =>
>   @order.signing_location_zip_code, :within => @miles, :conditions =>
>   "on_vacation IS NOT true",:order=>"distance asc")  like this,
>
> Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError in
>   Client/ordersController#find_notary
>
> Geokit::Geocoders::GeocodeError
>
> RAILS_ROOT: /home/user/svnnew_app/trunk/app
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@app/gems/geokit-1.5.0/lib/geokit/mappable.rb:282:in
>   `normalize'
>
> /home/user/svnnew_app/trunk/app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:347:in
>   `normalize_point_to_lat_lng'
>
> /home/user/svnnew_app/trunk/app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:306:in
>   `extract_origin_from_options'
>
> /home/user/svnnew_app/trunk/app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:203:in
>   `prepare_for_find_or_count'
>
> /home/user/svnnew_app/trunk/app/vendor/plugins/geokit-rails/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable.rb:108:in
>   `find'
>
> /home/user/svnnew_app/trunk/app/app/controllers/client/orders_controller.rb:331:in
>   `find_notary'
>
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"1198"}
>
> Show session dump Response
>
> Headers:
>
> {"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache",  "Content-Type"=>""}

How to resolve this error? Please help me out..

Comment: I had a similar error in Rails 4. Once I determined there was no error in my code, I realized I forgot to restart my server after making changes.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain geokit. I had a look at the source code and that line happens when the response back from the API isn't numeric, e.g. a string but not in the format '99.99, 88.88', so would happen if the geocoding API returned 'NA' or something for example.

And I know StackOverflow says "avoid" the following (clarification, opinion, etc.), but here it is:

I can't help further without you doing a few things:

1) If you could update to the latest geokit (gem: 1.7.1 or the latest github master)

2) Do some debugging, e.g. Open "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@app/gems/geokit-1.5.0/lib/geokit/mappable.rb" (line 282) and least "puts" the string that is causing the error along with any other relevant local variables.

Using gems like pry/pry-debugger are a must for any ruby developer to debugging such issues.

3) Update other software where possible (even upgrade to latest ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.x)
You're ruby (1.8.7) and rails (2.x) both are quite old and contain various security issues which should be of some concern. I do my best to keep geokit/geokit-rails working with ruby 1.8.7, but even rails 2 compatibility was dropped in geokit-rails, although I'm happy to help because likely you issue is a problem in geokit-rails with supported rails versions.